# java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed MySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, resultset, sqlexception

I keep getting this whenever I try to use this method.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7077)
    at server.util.Plimus$1.run(Plimus.java:77)
```

This is on line 77: `while (resultSet.next()) {`

```
public static void process(final Player c, final String playerName) {
    if (connection == null && connectionStatus == 0)
        createConnection();
    else if (connectionStatus != 0)
        return;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String username = playerName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
                String query = "SELECT * FROM donations WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND received = '0' LIMIT 1;";
                ResultSet resultSet = query(query);
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    int[] contractIds = {3178768, 1}; //put all of your contract ids in here.
                    int contractId = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("contract")), id = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("id"));
                    query("UPDATE donations SET received = '1' WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND id = '" + id + "';");
                    if (contractId == contractIds[0]) { //first contract id in array.
                        c.getItems().addItem(962, 1);
                    } else if (contractId == contractIds[1]) { //second contract id in array.
                        c.getItems().addItem(962, 1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                processMethod(0, true, true, false);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Here is the query method that is requested.

```
/**
 * Creates query function.
 */
public static ResultSet query(String s) throws SQLException {
    try {
        if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(s);
            return resultSet;
        } else {
            statement.executeUpdate(s);
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        processMethod(0, true, true, false);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get this exception?

Comment: also post query method

Comment: What does the query method do?

Comment: It updates information in my database.

Comment: A variable called `query` and a method called `query` in the same scope. Now *that's* a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

While iterating through your `ResultSet`, you are reusing the `Statement` object for updating the data (inside your `query` method), which closes the `ResultSet` from the query.

See the [ResultSet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> "A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results."

You should create separate Statements for the query and the update, and pass them to your query method:

```
public ResultSet query(String s, Statement statement) throws SQLException {
    ...
}
```

I assume that `statement` is declared `static` inside your class - there is usually no need for that: create the two statements for query and update in the constructor of your class, and either pass them to the `query()` method or use the one or the other depending on the statement.